# Fatal Error: spawn cmd ENOENT -- grunt serve

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to start my angular app using `grunt serve` command 
but I am getting Fatal error: spawn cmd ENOENT.

I used following commands to generate my Angular App

```
npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower
npm install -g generator-angular
yo angular
npm install
bower install
```

then i used `grunt serve` command to start my app

but its not working.

System Info:
OS: Windows 7 64 bit
npm version : 2.11.3[image]

please help me, I gone through all the grunt documentation but no clue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following possible solutions:

- Verify the npm folder exists at the following location C:\Users\My-UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm
- Try to run npm cache clean
- Add `C:\Windows\System32\` to the PATH Environment variable

Comment: this started happening to me after a Windows update - which had cleared out the windows environment system path variable; re-adding C:\Windows\System32\ fixed it for me (I also had to add in C:\Windows\System32\ and c:\program files\nodejs before I even got to this error).

Comment: Thanks a lot , this issue held me down for about a month i used another workaround to sort it out which is node express option .I just decided i must get to the bottom of the issue today and it is now resolved . I noticed it on my windows 10 box and i resolved it by simply adding C;Windows\System32 to my user and system environment .

Comment: Thanks @Luuk Moret

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but `C:\Windows\System32\ to the PATH` hint helped me resolve my issue with grunt-connect-proxy. Thanks a ton :)
`Loading "connect_proxy.js" tasks...ERROR`

Answer (score 1):

Run grunt serve with cmd.exe instead of git bash. I have the same problem and have dealt with it in this way.