# Fatal error: spawn cmd ENOENT - meanjs.org

Tags: node.js, meanjs, spawn, enoent

After successfully generating app using the following command

```
yo meanjs
```

I am trying to run grunt and here is the error that I am getting.

No idea what should i do, Already tried the following :

[stackoverflow question on something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398380/fatal-error-spawn-cmd-enoent-grunt-serve)

```
E:\akshay\torrent\Architecture of the MEAN Stack (OReilly 2015)\yo mean\final\fnl>grunt
Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Running "less:dist" (less) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 89 files lint free.

Running "eslint:target" (eslint) task

Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
>> 2 files lint free.

Running "mkdir:upload" task

Running "copy:localConfig" (copy) task


Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
    Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
    [nodemon] 1.10.2
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching: server.js config/**/*.js modules/*/server/**/*.js
    [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
    Running "watch" task
    Fatal error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    Waiting...
Warning:  Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: Why the tag "mean"? As far as I understand, this question does not have to do with the mathematical mean, which "mean" tag is for...

Comment: You are right, have remove the MEAN tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)