# How to resolve this gulp watch issue

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Error message:

```
    events.js:183
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Gulp build is working perfectly. But when I run gulp watch command  it will throw this exception. I have tried all the solutions. But not working for me.

Comment: Can you share your events.js file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398380/fatal-error-spawn-cmd-enoent-grunt-serve

This answer resolved my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398380/fatal-error-spawn-cmd-enoent-grunt-serve This answer resolved my problem